# How can I know the number of coins that I have collected?

Tags: temple-run-2

I want to unlock Maria Selva and for that I need 100,000 coins. But I don't know where to find the information about the number of coins I've collected.

Answer (score 1):

You can find this information in the statistics of your account. It is labelled "Total Coins" in the Lifetime subpart.

[image]